# Hovering over icons on top of an element with onMouseOver in react-konva

Tags: konvajs, react-konva

I have a `<Group/>` element containing a rectangle and a set of icons on top of the group that should only be visible if the user moves the cursor within the boundaries of that `<Group/>`'s contents. Wether the icons are being shown or not is triggered by an `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` event handler attached to the `<Group/>` object. I use a `useState` hook to save the hover state and hide/show the icons.

Displaying the icons `onMouseOver` works fine. But whenever the mouse cursor hovers over an icon,  the `onMouseOut` event of the `<Group/>` is triggered, thus hiding the icons. Moving the mouse over an icon shows/hides them in rapid succession (flashing).

Is there a way to force the `<Group/>` to *not* trigger an `onMouseOut` event if the cursor is still actually within it's area but on top of an icon (event bubbling?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to workaround this by using `React.useRef()` to store the hover state of the elements when they change and use the reference within a delayed function to decide what to do. In essence, something like this:

Setting up state, references and updating refs:

```
...

    const [isGroupHover, setIsGroupHover] = useState(false);
    const [isContextMenuHover, setIsContextMenuHover] = useState(false);

    const isContextMenuHovereRef = useRef(isContextMenuHover);
    const isGroupHoverRef = useRef(isGroupHover);

    useEffect(() => {
      isContextMenuHovereRef.current = isContextMenuHover;
      isGroupHoverRef.current = isGroupHover;
    }, [isGroupHover, isContextMenuHover]);

...
```

Intercepting the `<Group/>`'s `onMouseOut` event

```
...

    const onMouseOut = (e): void => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (!isContextMenuHovereRef.current) {
          setIsGroupHover(false);
        }
      }, 350);
    };

...
```

A function (`setIsContextMenuHover()`) is passed down to the context menu component via prop. This way, the context menu can pass it's own hover-state up the chain.

```
...

<ContextMenu setOnHover={setIsContextMenuHover} />

...
```

Essentially, this prevents the hover state of the `<Group/>`from being changed if the context menu is still visible or hovered over. A bit unwieldy - but it works.

Answer (score 1):

If your icons are not interactive and you don't need to listen to events for them, you can just set `listening = false`.

In that case, a node will be removed from hit graph and will not trigger `mouseenter`.

Comment: The icons are interactive, setting `listening=false` will prevent them from working.